Following ERC-6909 standard
I have a question on the implementation and specification of ERC-6909. In the standard, the type should be unit256 for multi-token ids. Can someone use a custom-type for token ids which is equivalent to "uint256"? In other words, if we define:
type XYZ is uint256;
and use type XYZ for token ids, would it still be compliant?
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6909
I reaches out to the authors and Ethereum foundation but was not able to get an answer.

The ERC-6909 standard in fact requires uint256 type as token ID.
Interpretations of the standard contents aside - technically, it is possible to use another type that can be ABI-encoded to uint256.
For example the following code
pragma solidity 0.8.27;

contract MyContract {
    type XYZ is uint256;

    function tokenURI(XYZ id) external view returns (string memory) {}
}

generates ABI that enables passing uint256 value of the id argument, even though the type is XYZ (that extends uint256).
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "MyContract.XYZ",
                "name": "id",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenURI",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

